# Filter out data from Spark dataframe by priority rules using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df, some sample records are mentioned below:

```
**customers**   **product**   **val_id**  
     1               A            1  
     2               C            r 
     3               B            X    
     4               D            X  
     5               E            1 
     6               F            9
```

I have some n number of rules that I have to apply on this data, Some sample rules are:

**Name:Rule 1, ID:1**

```
filter out customers who have product A and B, rule priority is 1
```

**Name:Rule 2, ID:2**

```
filter out customers who have product A, B,C and F, rule priority is 3
```

**Name:Rule 3, ID:3**

```
filter out customers who have product C and E, rule priority is 2
```

Requirement is that create a new dataframe and filter out those customers which are passed from these rules and also mention from which rule they passed, customers who passed from **priority 1** rule, should not be processed by lower priority rules and customers who passed from **priority 2** rule, should not be processed by low priority rules and so on.

So my final dataframe should be:

```
**customers**   **product**   **val_id**   **rule_name**   **rule_id** 
     1               A            1              Rule1           1
     2               C            r              Rule3           3
     3               B            X              Rule1           1
     5               E            1              Rule3           3
     6               F            9              Rule2           2
```

Can some one help me out to resolve this problem, using Spark Scala. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Out something like this:

```
val rule_name = when(col("product").isin("A","B"), "ABC").otherwise(when(col("product").isin("A","B","D"), "DEF").otherwise(""))
val rule_id = when(col("product").isin("A","B"), "123").otherwise(when(col("product").isin("A","B","D"), "456").otherwise(""))
val df1 = df_customers.withColumn("rule_name" , rule_name).withColumn("rule_id" , rule_id)
df1.show()
```

This is an example and might not be an exact solution, but you will be able to tackle your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by defining `udf` functions for `rule_name` and `rule_id` columns as

```
def rule_name = udf((product : String) => {
  if(Seq("A", "B").contains(product)) "Rule1"
  else if(Seq("A", "B", "C", "F").contains(product)) "Rule3"
  else if(Seq("C", "E").contains(product)) "Rule2"
  else ""
})

def rule_id = udf((product : String) => {
  if(Seq("A", "B").contains(product)) "1"
  else if(Seq("A", "B", "C", "F").contains(product)) "3"
  else if(Seq("C", "E").contains(product)) "2"
  else ""
})
```

Then call these `udf` functions using `withColumn` function as

```
val ruledDF = dataframe.withColumn("rule_name" , rule_name(col("product")))
  .withColumn("rule_id" , rule_id(col("product")))
```

Finally `filter` out the `rows` with empty rules

```
ruledDF.filter(!(ruledDF("rule_name") === ""))
```

That should have your requirements fulfilled.